# Write query for inserting varbinary value in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, varbinary

What is the syntax in PostgreSQL for inserting `varbinary` values?

SQL Server's syntax using a constant like `0xFFFF`, it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given there's no "varbinary" data type in Postgres I believe you mean "bytea". Take a look at the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html) about the way to specify "bytea" literals.

Depending on the language and the bindings you use  there could be more sophisticated ways for transferring binary data - you could find a .Net/C#/Npgsql example [here](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) (under "Working with binary data and bytea datatype").

Comment: thanks
that was exhaustive answer

ps luckily I use NHibernate to deal with all DB things)